# group results in one single line with similar ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
cat,
CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 52 THEN CCR.amount END earn,
CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 54 THEN CCR.amount END expend,

FROM fac_invoices CCR
GROUP BY CCR.cat, CCR.id_invoice_type , CCR.amount
ORDER BY CCR.cat
```

with the following result:

```
cat earn    expend
=======================
3   50,4    (null)
3   (null)  (null)
3   (null)  35
5   160,7   (null)
5   (null)  (null)
5   (null)  35
10  50,4    (null)
10  (null)  (null)
10  (null)  35
```

But I wanna get the current result

```
cat earn    expend
=======================
3   50,4    35
5   160,7   35
10  50,4    35
```

As you can see I have tried to group the fields but it's not working. What's wrong in my query? Or which other functions should I use to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SUM(case ... end)`

Comment: Remove Group by and apply distinct category in my observation cat is repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simplify the `GROUP BY`.  You want only one row per `cat`, so that should be the only key in the `GROUP BY`.  One way to do what you want is `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT cat,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 52 THEN CCR.amount END) as earn,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 54 THEN CCR.amount END) as expend
FROM fac_invoices CCR
GROUP BY CCR.cat
ORDER BY CCR.cat;
```

Or `MAX()` also works in your case.

```
SELECT cat,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 52 THEN CCR.amount END) as earn,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 54 THEN CCR.amount END) as expend
FROM fac_invoices CCR
GROUP BY CCR.cat
ORDER BY CCR.cat;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second option worked for me because `string_agg()` doesn't work with numeric fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `string_agg()` then like

```
CASE WHEN CCR.id_invoice_type = 52 THEN string_agg(CCR.amount,',') END earn,
```

Comment: I get an error using the function `string_agg()` with numeric values, like I commented on @GordonLinoff 's answer.